# SQL Server join statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to look at every row in `Examinations`, and for `Batra`, I want to update that column in `Patients` IF the value is 1 or 2.
A row for each patient already exists in `Patients`.

`Examinations`:

```
|ExaminationId | PatientId |    Batra |
---------------------------------------
|        12345 |       123 |        2 |
|        54321 |       123 |        1 |
|        98765 |       123 |        0 |
```

`Patients`:

```
|PatientId |    Batra |
-----------------------
|      123 |        0 |
```

The following is the result I want after performing this operation.

```
|PatientId | Batra|
-------------------
|      123 |    1 |
```

I have tried to produce some JOIN statement but I fail.

Edit: Something like this

```
UPDATE Patients
SET Patients.Batra = Examinations.Batra
WHERE Examinations.Batra = 1
OR Examinations.Batra = 2
```

Edit 2: It does not have to be set to 1. If 2 were the last value, it would be set to 2. Like this:

```
foreach(row in Examinations){
   if(row.Batra == 1 || row.Batra == 2){
      Patients.Batra = row.Batra
   }
}
```

Comment: How would you know which of the rows in `Examinations` to use? Highest `ExaminationId` with a non zero `Batra`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, I would just iterate through them all. It does not matter which one. It would not be a problem if I overwrote a value, as long as it was with 1 or 2.

Comment: Define *"Last Value"* ... would this be based on the `ExaminationId`? And what if it happens to be 0, do you still want an update in that case?

Comment: I still think iteratively I guess... You know what I mean? I just think like : go through every row, perform this operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this Query

```
UPDATE p
SET p.Batra = e.Batra
FROM Patients p
INNER JOIN Examinition e ON p.PatientId = e.PatientId 
WHERE e.Batra IN (1,2)
```

Comment: This will update patients twice or more if there is a lot of records for the same patient

Comment: @hellogoodnight you are better of using random number 1 or 2 instead of updating the same row 2 3 or i dont know how many times. that just unnecessary.

Comment: It is a one time operation so it does not matter that much

Comment: This will update using an arbitrary from batra. Not sure what @hellogoodnight is refering to when mentioning latest row, but this doesn't use any calculation for finding that latest row.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like this:

```
UPDATE
    Patients
SET
    Batra=em.batra
FROM
    Patients AS p
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            e.patientid,
            MAX(e.batra) AS batra
        FROM
            Examinations AS e
        GROUP BY
            e.patientid
    ) AS em ON
        em.patientid=p.patientid;
```

Comment: @hellogoodnight Your question is very confusing... I don't know if what I wrote is the correct answer tbh.

Answer (score 3):

I see you already got an answer, but this will update Patients with the latest (according to ExaminationId) `Batra` from examinations;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT patientid, batra, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PatientId ORDER BY ExaminationId DESC) rn
  FROM Examinations
  WHERE Batra IN (1,2)
)
UPDATE p
SET p.Batra = c.Batra
from patients p
JOIN cte c
  ON p.patientid = c.patientid
 AND c.rn = 1
```

The common table expression will rank the examinations with a 1 or 2 value for batra per patient by id, and the update will just use the latest value for each patient to update `patients`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use exists() function -

```
UPDATE Patients p
set batra = 1
where exists(select * from examinations e where e.patientid = p.patientid and e.barta in(1,2))
```

This checks if a batra with value 1 or 2 exists in examinations table and update the record in patient if there is.

Answer (score 2):

Go with simple join and fix where condition / updates ... but this is something you want

```
Update pat
    set Batra = exam.Batra
from patients pat
join Examinations exam on pat.patientID = exam.patientID
where exam.Batra in (1,2)
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution will find and update with the Batra value which is different from 0 and has the highest ExaminationId.

```
UPDATE
  p
SET
    Batra=em.batra
FROM
   Patients AS p
CROSS APPLY 
  (
    SELECT top 1
      e.batra
    FROM
      Examinations e
    WHERE
      e.patientid=p.patientid
      AND e.batra in (1,2)
    ORDER BY ExaminationId DESC
  ) AS em
```